# permission error when trying to use os.remove

Tags: python, glob

I have some code that if a certain folder exists, I want to remove it, and if the folder does not exist, I want to create that folder.

Below is my code:

```
import os
def build_file_structure(): 
    if os.path.exists('new data'):
        os.remove('new data')
    else: 
        os.mkdir('new data')
    source_dir = ''
    dst = 'new data'
    return source_dir, dst 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    source_dir, dst = build_file_structure()
```

The code works fine when there is no folder "newdata", but when the "newdata" folder exists prior to running I receive this error:

```
os.remove('new data')
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'new data'
```

Comment: `os.remove` is meant for deleting files. Try using `os.rmdir`.

Comment: That's it, thank you!

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote them and accept the best one. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.rmdir` (remove directory) in order to remove folders.

```
os.rmdir('new data')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try using any one of the below

**Using shell util library**

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree(dir_path)
```

Traditional `os` module

```
os.rmdir(dir_path)
```